# Обращение к контейнеру vector, который находится внутри контейнера map

Tags: c++, vector, map

Есть контейнер `map<string,vector<string>> Map`.
Требуется найти определённое слово в векторе и вывести его ключ. Отсюда вопрос: как обратиться к вектору, который находится внутри map?

Comment: К *какому именно* вектору? Их там много, по одному у каждого элемента. Если на нужный вам элемент указывает, скажем, итератор `it`, то вектор - `it->second`...

Comment: можно через `operator[]`, через `at` или по итератору - ровно так же как и к любому другому типу значения в `map`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос не понятно оформлен, но, насколько я понял, вы хотите в векторе искать строку являющийся ключом?
Тогда, например, так:

```
for (auto& p : Map)    
    for (const auto& str : p.second) {
        if (p.first == str)
            std::cout << p.first;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Пример, как можно работать с такой картой: обращаться к элементу и искать определённый элемент в каком-то векторе.

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    const std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> Map = {
        {"0", {"hello", "world",}},
        {"1", {"world", "hello",}},
    };

    const auto& first_vector = Map.at("0");
    const auto& first_word_in_first_vector = first_vector[0];

    const auto word_pos = std::find(std::cbegin(first_vector), std::cend(first_vector), "world");

    std::cout << "access: " << first_word_in_first_vector << '\n'
              << "found_word: " << *word_pos << '\n';
}
```

Доки:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find

Comment: стоит ли попытаться перемещать  данные mapped_type в другой  объект?.. У вектора есть свой begin() . стоит ли обращаться к  std::begin(), когда известно что это точно для std::vector? А могли бы сразу:   `auto word_pos = std::find(Map["0"].begin(), Map["0"].end(), "world");
    if(word_pos != Map["0"].end())
      std::cout  << *word_pos << '\n';` И, насколько я понял, нужно  было выполнить  это

Comment: @ARHovsepyan 1) я ничего не перемещал; 2) да, стоит; 3) для наглядности назвал переменные, чтобы было понятно, что происходит

Comment: а я и не говорил, что вы перемещали, я говорил, что вы попытались это делать. 2. По какой логике стоит? Писать лишний `std::` вызвать ее, чтобы она вызвала  ту же std::vector<Ty>::begin()? Не говорю, что это ошибка...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan что значит попытался? :) Пытался-пытался, но не получилось? :) 2) По той логике, что это более обобщённый подход, если вы захотите поменять вектор на массив, то мой вариант продолжит работать, а ваш - нет

Comment: @ARHovsepyan если это вы поставили минус, то объясните, что в ответе неверно или почему он не полезен ТС?

Comment: Я уже объяснил свою точку зрения, и  это чисто моя точка зрения .. Я ничего не хочу доказывать, и не говорю, что код неверный, не считая, что разыменовывать итератор без  проверки    на выход за конец, тоже является  грубой  ошибкой, которую вам стоит исправлять. Я говорил, что у вас  слишком много лишней писанины, лишних имен и неуместных auto&&. И обобщенный подход нужен для обобщенных алгоритмов, а не для конкретных типов.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan если вам не нравится этот стиль программирования, это не повод ставить минус. Вы говорите про лишнюю писанину, при этом называя ненаписание проверки в моём примере грубой ошибкой, учитывая что значение для поиска задаётся литералом через 2 строки от создания вектора с таким значением

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110956/discussion-between-ar-hovsepyan-and-dim0n).

Comment: @ARHovsepyan чего не отвечаете?

Comment: сколько можно продолжать тему? Я не хочу, тема для меня закрыта

Comment: @ARHovsepyan снимите минус - и тема будет закрыта 