# Поиск элемента вектора в другом векторе

Tags: c++, vector

Нужно сделать что-то вроде этого

```
for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++){
    /// if(v1.find(v[i]) != -1){ ///
        cout<<"YES";
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Надо найти все такие элементы вектора 1, которые встречаются в векторе 2?

Comment: Хорошо, и в чем именно проблема?

Comment: Неважно хочу просто найти элемент первого вектора который есть во втором

Comment: Любой элемент, который есть? Вектора произвольных длин или один сильно меньше другого?

Comment: Вам пересечение векторов нужно?

Comment: Я хочу вывести все элементы из первого вектора которые имеются во втором векторе

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Я хочу вывести все элементы из первого вектора которые имеются во
> втором векторе

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::vector a{5, 4, 1, 9, 12, 7},
                b{3, 8, 12, 3, 42, 9};

    std::sort(std::begin(a), std::end(a));
    std::sort(std::begin(b), std::end(b));

    std::set_intersection(std::cbegin(a), std::cend(a),
                          std::cbegin(b), std::cend(b),
                          std::ostream_iterator<decltype(a)::value_type>{std::cout, "\n"});
}
```

Comment: тип элементов  известен и  std::vector  имеет свои  begin и end.  Чтобы  написать свое имя, не нужно пользоваться услугами паспортного стола...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan мы уже это обсуждали. Спор ни к чему не привёл, так зачем снова вскрывать эту тему :)

Comment: Мы это кто? Я не обсуждал, но только я всегда осуждаю излишние телодвижения  и  замусорование кода

Comment: @ARHovsepyan https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1156556/398802 и https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110956/discussion-between-ar-hovsepyan-and-dim0n

Comment: Мне как то не интересует в этом плане мнение других, и я даже не буду смотреть. Я понимаю так: если можно сказать, что это яйцо, то не нужно говорить, что это то существо, которое несет птица, а  может и не птица.... Можно конечно  показывать все свои знания языка и инструментов даже при объявлении объекта, но кому это нужно? Удивить народ своими знаниями, который только начинает изучать?...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan вы уже говорили это, и я вам отвечал по этим ссылкам

Comment: А есть такая функция по типу find, для поиска конкретного элемента первого вектора во втором векторе?

Comment: @LegoLas для 1 элемента как раз find и есть. Возможно, вам [search](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/search) нужен? Вообще, все алгоритмы из `<algorithm>` [тут](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/algorithm) перечислены, можете поискать подходящий